# Extract values from a curve in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, extract, curve

I have a plot of values X and Y in MATLAB. I want to extract values of Y from the plot at certain values of X - in order to then use these values for another calculation. However, I need to extract these values at different intervals than the original dataset that was used to create the plot. How can I sample these points from the plot in MATLAB?

This is probably very straightforward but I'm new to MATLAB!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the actual MATLAB plot, you can retrieve the plotted data by finding the line object and getting its `XData` and `YData` properties:

```
hline = findobj(gca,'type','line');
x = get(hline,'XData');
y = get(hline,'YData');
```

The above assumes that the plot is the "current axes", which you can ensure by clicking on it before running that code. It also assumes that there is only one line object (one graph).

Now `x` and `y` contain the data plotted. You wanted to sample that at different x values. This you can do with `interp1`:

```
newx = 0:0.1:10; % or whatever values of x
newy = interp1(x,y,newx);
```

By default this uses linear interpolation, as does the plotted graph. If you prefer you can choose a different interpolation method, for example:

```
newy = interp1(x,y,newx,'spline');
```